# How to code Full-text-search ( by Lucene) in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, lucene, full-text-search

My project is about an online mobile shopping.

I'm using Where Like to set the Search controller.But now,I want to use Full-text-search (by Lucene).

I follow this tut http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html.

But I dont know how to code in my project (rails 4)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sunspot gem which did a great integration of rails and solr/lucene. https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot

Comment: I already using solr gem,but I'm finding another way like coding java in rails

Answer (score 0):

You should install sunspot gem as told above and use the following code

```
 @search=Sunspot.search(Model name) do
         fulltext params[:search]
         end
```

The Above code will search your model for the params value in param[:search] in @search